# Is IIS Blocking My Callback?

Tags: jquery, rest, callback, cross-domain, jsonp

- When I try the code below in Cassini, I get a valid response.
- When I make the following RESTful call in a browser, I see a valid response -  `http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?command=find_all_videos&page_size=1&video_fields=name&token=[token]`.
- But when I host my website in IIS 7.5, my callback function receives a `null` argument.

My Question:

> Could IIS 7.5 be blocking the
>   response?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateReadToken() {
            $.getJSON("http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?command=find_all_videos&page_size=1&video_fields=name&token=[token]",
                function (data) {
                    alert(data.items.length);
                }
            );
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a").click(function (event) {
                validateReadToken();
            });
        });    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Jim, JS would only ever run on the client (the web browser) so I don't think IIS would be in the chain here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help.

Indeed, I needed to pay attention to the fact that I was trying to make a cross-domain request.

To get around this limitation, I need to use JSONP.

- [JSONP Explanation 1](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/)
- [JSONP Explanation 2](http://www.openg.info/question/jquery-retrieve-data-localhost)
- [Concise Code Example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/)

---

New Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateReadToken() {
            var url = 'http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?command=find_all_videos&page_size=1&video_fields=name&token=[token]';
            $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?", function (data) {
                alert(data.items.length);
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a").click(function (event) {
                validateReadToken();
            });
        });    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth reading through this: http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/using-xmlhttp-make-calls-proxy.

I'm not an AJAX expert but hosting your site on your own IIS server and then making service requests against brightcove would seem to fall under the umbrella of cross domain issues.

Perhaps trying a server-side proxy would be the way forward.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: +1: *...hosting your site on your own IIS server and then making service requests against brightcove would seem to fall under the umbrella of cross domain issues.* - You are absolutely right.